# isNotBlank(inputString) vs isNotEmpty(inputString)

Tags: apex, string

For string in Apex code, I can see two functions to check if string has any value or not: `isNotBlank(inputString)` and `isNotEmpty(inputString)`.
I have following questions regarding two similar looking function:

1. What is the difference between `isNotBlank(inputString)` and `isNotEmpty(inputString)`?
2. Can these functions also detect if inputString is `null`?

While I used above function with empty string, both behaved similarly (i.e. returned false). For null value as well both function returned false. Just confused when to use which function out of isNotBlank and isNotEmpty.

Comment: This question shows very little research effort. In the future, I recommend taking a close look at the documentation first. Questions clearly answered by the documentation on whatever class you are asking about often receive down votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR - If you want to return `false` when the input is whitespace, use `isNotBlank`. If you want this value to return `true` instead, use `isNotEmpty`.

---

This question is plainly answered in the documentation:

> **isNotBlank(inputString)**
> Returns true if the specified String is not whitespace, not empty (''), and not null; otherwise, returns false.

> ...

> **Example**

> ```
> String alpha = 'Hello world!';
> ```

```
System.assert(String.isNotBlank(alpha));
String blank = '';
String nullString = null;
String whitespace = '  ';
System.assert(!String.isNotBlank(blank));
System.assert(!String.isNotBlank(nullString));
System.assert(!String.isNotBlank(whitespace));
```

> **isNotEmpty(inputString)**
> Returns true if the specified String is not empty ('') and not null; otherwise, returns false.

> ...

> **Example**

> ```
> String whitespace = '  ';
> ```

```
String alpha = 'Hello world!';
System.assert(String.isNotEmpty(whitespace));
System.assert(String.isNotEmpty(alpha));
String empty = '';
String nullString = null;
System.assert(!String.isNotEmpty(empty));
System.assert(!String.isNotEmpty(nullString));
```

Comment: According to your detail null would return false for both. Your asserts show that as well since your are negating the result. Did I miss something

Comment: I just tested both notEmpty and notBlank with a null value and it returns false on both of them. A bit confused by your TL;DR

Answer (score 2):

From salesforce page
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isNotBlank

**isNotBlank(inputString)**
Returns true if the specified String is not whitespace, not empty (''), and not null; otherwise, returns false.

**isNotEmpty(inputString)**
Returns true if the specified String is not empty ('') and not null; otherwise, returns false.

Comment: It's hard to see what this answer adds which is not contained in the answer posted several months ago.

Comment: In the above comment, the distinction is made on null but on salesforce page, you can see both methods return true for null.

Comment: Correct this answer adds little value, except it is easier to read, and references the documentation.

New documentation is out now and it is much better I believe.

The above comment, the salesforce page has never suggested a null returns true.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isNotBlank